# How can I use sum of columns in where in postgres sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sum, sequelize.js

I have problem in my query I have query to get result with sum of one column :

```
const { Op, literal, fn, col } = this.app.Sequelize;

const timeTableWhere = {
  [Op.and]: [
    {
      durationTimestamp: {
        [Op.gte]: hourTimestamp,
      },
    },
  ],
};
const timetables = await ctx.model.Timetable.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'userId',
    'dow',
    'type',
    [fn('SUM', col('duration_timestamp')), 'durationTimestamp'],
  ],
  where: timeTableWhere,
  group: ['dow', 'userId', 'type'],
});
```

Now I want check `hourTimestamp` with sum of `duration_timestamp` column in my `where`
but my condition just check value of one column.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey I resolved this problem with add having in my query like this :

```
const { Op, literal, fn, col ,where} = this.app.Sequelize;
    const timetables = await ctx.model.Timetable.findAll({
      attributes: [
        'userId',
        'dow',
        'type',
        [fn('SUM', col('duration_timestamp')), 'durationTimestamp'],
      ],
      having:{
         [Op.and]: [
           where(fn('SUM', col('duration_timestamp')) , { [Op.gte]: hourTimestamp,})
                   ],
             },
      group: ['dow', 'userId', 'type'],
    });
```